# Отправить изображение в диалог вк посредством VkNet

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

Авторизуемся в вк через токен сообщества(!)

```
 var api = new VkApi();api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
{
    AccessToken = "мой_токен",

});
```

И нужно отправить изображение некоторому пользователю в лс.
Сложность заключается  том,что авторизация проходит через токен сообщества,а не через аккаунт пользователя,а значит через UploadServer не получается загружать изображение на сервер.
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [photos.getMessagesUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getMessagesUploadServer).

---

**Простой пример:**

- Ваша авторизация:

  ```
  var api = new VkApi();
  api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
  {
      AccessToken = "мой_токен"
  });
  ```
- Далее получаем сервер:

  ```
  var uploadServer = api.Photo.GetMessagesUploadServer(id_пользователя);
  ```
- Загружаем изображение:

  ```
  var wc = new WebClient();
  var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(uploadServer.UploadUrl, @"Путь_до_файла"));
  ```
- Получаем загруженные изображения в виде коллекции (метод [photos.saveMessagesPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveMessagesPhoto)):

  ```
  var photo = api.Photo.SaveMessagesPhoto(result);
  ```
- Осталось отправить сообщение:

  ```
  api.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams()
  {
      UserId = id_пользователя,
      Message = "сообщение",
      Attachments = new List<MediaAttachment>
      {
          photo.FirstOrDefault() //берем первое фото из коллекции.
      }
  });
  ```